# While loop stops after 1 iteration

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, while-loop, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

As one of my first projects trying to learn python I decided to make an RC car. But now I've been stuck with the same 2 problems for a long time, and can't find a real good answer. In my code for the moment, I connect to my raspberry through bluetooth from my phone. When I send simple commands, the care moves. But I also added 3 sensors so I could build some sort of autopilot, where the car evades objects in his path.
My code: https://pastebin.com/ggUFcrpT

```
def serialread():
 while True:
   line = ser.read()

   print line

   if line == 's':
      ser.write("Abandom ship! \n")
      resetmotorpins()
   elif line == 'f':
      ser.write("Going forward, captain! \n")
      resetmotorpins()
      forward()
   elif line == 'r':
      ser.write("Dizzy! \r\n")
      resetmotorpins()
      right()
   elif line == 'l':
      ser.write("If nothing goes right, go left! \n")
      resetmotorpins()
      left()
   elif line == 'b':
      ser.write("nah fam, i'm out, f*ck this shiet. \r\n")
      resetmotorpins()
      reverse()
   elif line == "t":
       ser.write("autoPilot activate \n")
       auto = 1
       resetmotorpins()
       while auto == 1:
        line = ser.read()    
        if line == "y":
            ser.write("autoPilot deactivated \n")
            resetmotorpins()
            auto = 0
        else:
            meet()

   elif line == "m":
      meet()
   elif line == 'o':
      servomotorright()
   elif line == 'x':
      servomotorleft()
   elif line == 'q':
      waardesVragen()
```

I think it gets stuck at the `line = ser.read()` and that it needs a line to run through the code. But I have no idea how to make it just loop constantly and make somekind of interupt when I send a letter/command.

On top of that I'm trying to initialize mulithreading so I can print my values from the 3 sensor constantly and make an interrupt when it's close to hitting an object. But the multithreading seems to not be working, once I got into the sensor value printing, it never leaves that loop and doesn't listen to my bluetooth connection anymore.
Any suggestions? I hope I posted this right, it's my first question here.
I'm using python 2.7.5 on a raspberry pi B

Comment: So when you run this code does it get to the point where it prints out the line to the terminal? Or does it hang at line = ser.read()

Comment: When I send a letter, it prints it out but the problem is that it has to keep looping in the while loop until I send the stop-command. And I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: It might be something that is hanging within the resetmotorpins() function, bc if that function wasn't there it looks like it would go back through the while loop